# Server error after a local installation of prestashop on mamp

Tags: mysql, localhost, prestashop

Good morning,

I installed prestashop locally on mamp, it worked for a few hours and then after I got this error message: 500 Server Error
Oops, something went wrong.

Try to refresh this page or feel free to contact us if the problem persists. I changed the port, I changed the php version, it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me ?

I changed the port, I changed the php version, it still doesn't work.

Can anyone help me ?